# How to add single quotes around multiple strings

Tags: r, string, text

```
strings <- c("apple", "banana", "029")
> strings
[1] "apple"  "banana" "029"
```

I would like to add single quotes to each element in `strings` and separate the strings with `,`. My desired output is this:

```
desired_strings <- "'apple','banana','029'"
> desired_strings
[1] "'apple','banana','029'"
```

My attempt:

```
a <- "'"
paste0(mapply(paste0, a, strings, a), ",")
[1] "'apple',"  "'banana'," "'029',"
```

However, this is not quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sQuote()` and then collapse to a single string with `paste()`:

```
paste(sQuote(strings, q = FALSE), collapse = ",")

[1] "'apple','banana','029'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf`.

```
toString(sprintf("'%s'", strings))
# [1] "'apple', 'banana', '029'"
```

or

```
paste(sprintf("'%s'", strings), collapse=",")
# [1] "'apple','banana','029'"
```